# How to enable and disable HTML's disabled property

Tags: javascript, jquery, css, html

I am constructing an HTML button object inside a function. I want to **enable** or **disable** the button depending on a condition from this function's parameter. I have simplified my problem to the code below:

```
function test(condition) {
    var html = ""

    var enableBtn = false;

    if (condition == true) {
        enableBtn = true;
    } else {
        enableBtn = false;
    }

    html += '<button type="button" disabled="' + enableBtn + '"> Click </button></div>';

    $("#testLocation").html(html);
}
```

The problem here is that the `disabled` flag does not work with **true** or **false**. According to the official HTML5 specs:

https://www.w3.org/TR/html5/forms.html#enabling-and-disabling-form-controls:-the-disabled-attribute

https://www.w3.org/TR/html5/infrastructure.html#boolean-attribute,

only valid options for `disabled` are

```
<input type="text" disabled />
<input type="text" disabled="" />
<input type="text" disabled="disabled" />
```

So how do I get around this? I also tried setting `disabled = null` but that does not work.

Comment: `if (condition = true)` should be `if (condition == true)`

Comment: just set enableBtn  = "disabled" or enableBtn = "".

Comment: in case your button have id attribute you can directly use jquery attr('disabled',false) or set it to true

Comment: @j08691 thanks for catching that, was a typo

Comment: `if(condition) {$el.attr('disabled', 'disabled');} else {$el.removeAttr('disabled')}`?

Answer (score 1, accepted):

You can also use empty string if condition is not true and assign `enableBtn` to `disabled` if true.

```js
function test(condition) {
        var html = ""

        var enableBtn = '';

        if (condition == true) {
            enableBtn = 'disabled';
        } else {
            enableBtn = '';
        }

        html += '<button type="button" ' + enableBtn + '> Click </button></div>';

        $("#testLocation").html(html);
    }
    
    $('#test').on('click', function() {
      test(true)
    });
```

```html
<script src="https://ajax.googleapis.com/ajax/libs/jquery/2.1.1/jquery.min.js"></script>
<button id="test">Test button</button>
<div id="testLocation"></div>
```

Comment: @OneMoreQuestion I have added a code snippet and it's working.

Answer (score 1):

add/remove `disabled` attribute

```
$(input).attr('disabled','disabled')

$(input).removeAttr('disabled')
```

Try below code.

```
function test(condition) {
    var btn = $('<button type="button"> Click </button></div>');

    if (condition == true) {
       btn.attr('disabled','disabled')
    } else {
      // btn.removeAttr('disabled') dont need this..we will add disabled only if required.    
    }

    $("#testLocation").html(btn);
}
```

---

Or you could do like this

```
function test(condition) {
    $("#testLocation").html('<button type="button" '+(condition?'disabled':'')+'> Click </button></div>');
}
```

Comment: I am trying to set the flag before I construct the element

Comment: @OneMoreQuestion did you try the above? :)

Answer (score 1):

Disabled is a "boolean attribute," which is just a fancy spec way of saying that the attribute is considered "true" if present (whether you use `disabled="spaghetti"` or `disabled="disabled"` is irrelevant), and "false" if absent. Thus, you actually need to toggle *whether or not the attribute is added* to your HTML element, instead of simply changing its value.

From [the page you linked](https://www.w3.org/TR/html5/infrastructure.html#boolean-attribute):

> **Note:** The values "true" and "false" are not allowed on boolean attributes. To represent a false value, the attribute has to be omitted altogether.

```js
function test(condition) {
  $('#testLocation').html(
    '<button type="button" ' + (condition ? 'disabled' : '') + '>Click</button></div>'
  )
}

test(true)
```

```html
<script src="//ajax.googleapis.com/ajax/libs/jquery/2.1.1/jquery.min.js"></script>
<div id="testLocation"></div>
```

Comment: Thanks this works, I have upvoted your answer. @julekgwa's answer if more simple so I accepted his

Comment: Thank you for the upvote :) I'm not sure how my answer is more complicated than the one you accepted, though -- mine is quite a few lines shorter.

Answer (score 0):

Try these..

```
$('#input').prop('disabled', true);

$('#input').prop('disabled', false);
```

Comment: I am trying to set the flag before I construct the element

Answer (score 0):

This always works for me when I want to toggle `disabled`:

```
$("#testLocation").setAttribute("disabled, "");
```

Very straightforward. And if you want to remove it,

```
$("#testLocation").removeAttribute("disabled");
```

This does not require a second parameter.